# Symmetric normalised Laplacian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, laplacian

I have the relation for symmetric Laplacian matrix:
\begin{equation}
L=I-D^{-1/2}AD^{-1/2}
\end{equation}

I know the matrix $L$ and now I am wondering if I can use the above relationship to calculate matrix $A$.  Obviously $D$ is unknown as well.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: $D$ is just the diagonal matrix whose nonzero elements are vertex degrees.

Comment: Exactly. I did ask a different thing though

Comment: If $D$ is unknown then you can't solve for $A$ in terms of $L$.

Comment: In order to know $D$ I should know A right? $D$ is calculated from the nonzero elements of A.

Comment: $D$ just tells you the degrees, nothing more specific than that. $A$ has more information in it.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the unweighted graph without loops. As you know L, you could infer $D$ by merely calculating the non-zero non-diagonal elements for each row $L_{ij} = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{d_i d_j}}$. I.e., $d_1$ will be the number of non-zero $L_{1j}, j\neq1$.

The further is simple: $$ A = D - \sqrt{D}L \sqrt{D}$$.

Comment: So I can estimate $D$ using $L_{ij}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt {d_id_j}}$? If so, how did you derive that formula?

Comment: @Gina, this is according to the definition of the Laplacian matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix).